# Why do I need a delay before showing AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, ui-thread

Under some conditions, when my app starts, it displays an AlertDialog.  However, the alert never gets displayed.  I discovered that if I add a delay, it works (i.e. gets displayed).

More specifically: on app startup, it executes the main activity onCreate() which under a certain condition starts a 2nd activity.  In the 2nd activity, through a separate thread, it makes a check for some web server status.  If the Android device doesn't have Internet connectivity, HttpURLConnection returns an error instantly and my enclosing function executes a callback to the 2nd activity.  My code then uses post() to attempt to display an alert to the user (using post allows displaying the alert on the UI thread, which is required).

Apparently it tries to display the alert before any of the either activity's UI has been created.  If I use postDelayed() in the 2nd activity, the problem still persists.  However, if I use the following block of code in the main activity, the alert shows properly:

```
new Handler().postDelayed (new Runnable ()
{
  @Override public void run()
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent (app, MyClass.class);
    app.startActivityForResult (intent, requestCode);
  }
}, 3000);
```

My solution is a hack that happens to work at the moment.  I don't mind having a little delay on start-up for this particular situation but I don't want a delay that's longer than necessary or one that may sometimes fail.

What is the proper solution?

Comment: at which point do you call web api in 2nd activity (onCreate, onResume) ?

Comment: onCreate().  That gets me thinking: it's worth a try moving it to onStart() or onResume().

Comment: I guess moving to other life cycle method will not help, I still not sure I fully get the situation but my guess is that your alert dialog tires to attach to 2nd activity whereas it should be shown on 1st one because you are moving user back in case of fail.

Comment: Well, moving the server interaction to onStart() or onResume() didn't make any difference.  The alert definitely belongs to the 2nd activity.  But just for kicks I'm going to try creating an AlertDialog in onCreate() of the main activity...

Comment: That worked - when I call AlertDialog immediately, as opposed to through a post after calling the web service, my alert shows.   It's starting to look like a divide and conquer problem.

Comment: Could you possibly post more code etc about your issue. This race condition looks really interesting. Thank you.

Comment: I can, but it would help to know what you're looking for.  I suspect the problem is that onCreate() is being called from Android before the UI thread looper has started.  I haven't looked at how the looper gets started so I could be completely off base.  I did work out a solution.  I'm going to post that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a workaround.  First, I'll speculate that the problem is that the attempt to display the alert is happening before the looper for the UI thread has been started.  Just a speculation.

To work around the problem I added a recursive post which gets called from onResume(), like this:

```
private boolean paused = true;

@Override public void onResume ()
{
  super.onResume();
  paused = false;
  checkForAlert();
}

@Override public void onPause ()
{
  super.onPause();
  paused = true;
}
```

And here's the function that does the post:

```
private AlertInfo alertInfo = null;

private void checkForAlert()
{
  if (alertInfo != null)
  {
    ...code to build alert goes here...
    alertInfo = null;
  }

  if (!paused)
    contentView.postDelayed (new Runnable()
    {
      @Override public void run() { checkForAlert(); }
    }, 200);
}
```

AlertInfo is a simple class where the thread needing the alert can put the relevant info, e.g. title, message.

So, how does this work?  checkForAlert() gets called during onResume() and will continue to get called every 200ms until "paused" is false, which happens in onPause().  It's guaranteed to be recurring whenever the activity is displayed.  The alert will get built and displayed if alertInfo is not null.  In the secondary thread, I simply create an AlertInfo instance and then within 200ms the alert gets displayed.  200ms is short enough that most people won't notice the delay.  It could be shorter but then battery use goes up.

Why did I start checkForAlert() in onResume instead of onCreate()? Simply because there's no need for it to run unless the activity is currently "on top".  This also helps with battery life.